# Phonegap and interstitial ads

Tags: android, cordova, interstitial

I'm trying to display interstitial ads on a phonegap app but i just can't make it work.
I have followed this tutorial from google https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced?csw=1#play but the ads don't show. 
I think a need a trigger in my html to make the ads popup but how do I do it?

I'm a newbie, so any help is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this phonegap plugin https://github.com/aliokan/cordova-plugin-admob